# Call some Matlab functions knowing their names

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have `func1`, `func2` and `func3`. Is there any way to call them with a known argument having defined their names? (Or their pointers? handlers?)

Something like:

```
toBeRunned = [ 'func1'; 'func2'; 'func3' ];
// .. foreach entry of toBeRunned call the function with VAR params ..
```

Comment: You should probably want to use cell array (`cell()` function and `{}` literals) for storing strings, because you can store strings of different sizes within it. Check Pursuit's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what function handles are meant for.

```
toBeRun = {@func1, @func2, @func3};
for ix = 1:length(toBeRun)
    fnArguments = {1, 2, 3, 'four'};
    fnTmp = toBeRun{ix};
    fnTmp(fnArguments{:});
end
```

A little more explanation on what we're doing here:

1. toBeRun is a cell array of function handles, just an arbitrary list.  For a function written as an M-file, added the `@` is all the is required to create a function handle.
2. In order to evaluate the function,  it needs to be removed from the cell array (into `fnTmp` in this case.)  This is a syntax limitation of Matlab.  You can also use `fneval`, but I usually do it this way.
3. Any arguments can be added as needed, in the usual way (e.g. `fnTmp(1,2,3,'four')`).  But if you need this much abstraction, you may also need to use an arbitrary number of input arguments.  The `fnArguments` cell is a pretty flexible way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3):

Function [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html):

```
for i = 1 : size(toBeRunned, 1)
    feval(toBeRunned(i, :), argument);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish it...

```
toBeRunned = { 'func1', 'func2', 'func3' };

% arguments to be provided to functions
VAR = { arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 };

% preallocate space for results 
results = cell(1, 3);

for i = 1 : length(toBeRunned)
    % KEY part ...
    toRun = eval( [ '@' boBeRunned{i} ] );
    results{i} = toRun( VAR{:} );
end
```

Explanation of the *key* part of the code:

- `[]` concatenates strings,
- `eval` evaluates string as Matlab code. In the first iteration of the loop, line with `eval` equals to:

  ```
  toRun = @func1;
  ```